# ggplot2: change the background color of one of the legend elements

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the background color for one legend element but not the rest. For example, using the built in R dataset `ToothGrowth`

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose,y=len,colour=supp)) +
  geom_point()
```

Rather than change the color of the dots themselves, I want to change the background color of the box in the legend from grey to another color for only one of the legend elements. For instance change the background of `VC` but not `OJ`.

[image]

Comment: what are VC and OJ?

Comment: share a reproducible example for better clarification @phaser

Comment: I used a built in data set in R. So the example should be reproducible.

Comment: You can change the legend background colour using `theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "yellow"))`. But I don't believe it's possible to use different colours in your case, since its is the variable (`supp`) which maps to the legend, not its values.

Comment: You could hack around this by adding something like `geom_tile(height = 0, width = 0, aes(fill = supp)) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "white"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a hack because you use the `{magick}` package but it gives the desired output:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)

fig <- image_graph(width = 1000, height = 500, res = 96)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose,y=len,colour=supp)) +
  geom_point()
dev.off()

fig %>% 
  image_fill("lightblue", point = "+950+220", fuzz = 5)
```

`image_fill()` is the equivalent of the paint bucket in MSPaint

[image]